# Change a field in django's admin view

Tags: python, django, admin

I'd like to know if there is a way to override a field in a view for django's admin. I'd like to show a particular information in my view when a specific field is displayed. I already read the documentation about [how to customize the default behaviour of django's admin module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template). For example, I was looking in `includes/fieldset.html`, but I couldn't find a `block` tag to override it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably the formkey for ForeignKey function of the django admin.

> The formfield_for_foreignkey method on a ModelAdmin allows you to override the default formfield for a foreign keys field. For example, to return a subset of objects for this foreign key field based on the user:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "car":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Car.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

> This uses the HttpRequest instance to filter the Car foreign key field to only display the cars owned by the User instance.

[Read the doc on the django.contrib.admin for a better understanding](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm looking for a change in the view/template not a model.